# Animate sprite position randomly

Tags: animation, position, libgdx, sprite, tween

I'm using Tween Engine in my LibGDX project, and was wondering if there is a way of animating the position of sprites randomly and loop it, or check if a tween animation is over?

Comment: Could you pleae be more specific what your goal is or provide some code of things you already tried?  Also if you have two questions, that seem unrelated (random positioning vs is a tween anim over), you should ask them separatly.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. The purpose i asked to check if a tween animation is over is that i could recall the tween when it's over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found at my problem is by creating a method like this:

```
public void tweenSprite(float x, float y, float currX, float currY){
    Tween.set(sprite, SpriteAccessor.POSXY).target(currX, currY).start(tweenManager);
    Tween.to(sprite, SpriteAccessor.POSXY, 5 + r.nextInt(5)).target(x, -y).setCallback(new TweenCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
            tweenSprite(r.nextInt(60), r.nextInt(60), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
        }
    }).start(tweenManager);
}
```